# Castbutton greyed out

Tags: android, chromecast

I am new to app android development trying to create a simple "Chromecast Hello world".

Unfortunately, the Cast-Button was not displayed. After forcing visibility it is greyed out all the time, and I can't identify the reason.

Here is what I have so far:

OptionsProvider:

```
public class ChromecastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
        CastOptions castOptions = new CastOptions.Builder()
                //.setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id))
                .build();
        return castOptions;
    }

    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private CastContext mCastContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);

        MediaRouteButton mMediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
        CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(), mMediaRouteButton);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton
       android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
       android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello world" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am starting / debugging the app on my actual real device, which is connected to my local Wifi, which contains a normal CHromecast.

Since there is no error message or anything, I can't find the reason.
Hopefully, someone can help me out.

Comment: U want a button and a textview to be placed horizontally?

Comment: I want the cast-button to be clickable, no matter where it is placed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I double checked with sample implementation at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cast-videos-android/

It turns out, that 
1. I have to provide an receiver application id (I thought when using default, it can be skipped)
2. The receiver app have to be supported by the device

So I changed my ChromecastOptionsProvider-class:

```java
public class ChromecastOptionsProvider implements OptionsProvider {

    @Override
    public CastOptions getCastOptions(Context context) {
        CastOptions castOptions = new CastOptions.Builder()
                .setReceiverApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.app_id)) //using "4F8B3483" works
                .build();
        return castOptions;
    }

    @Override
    public List<SessionProvider> getAdditionalSessionProviders(Context context) {
        return null;
    }
}
```